# Find the sum of all products of two distinct naturals, neither exceeding 2015.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Find the sum

> $$(1\cdot2)+(1\cdot3)+(1\cdot4)+\cdots+(1\cdot2015)+(2\cdot3)+(2\cdot4)+\cdots+(2\cdot2015)+\cdots+(2014\cdot2015)$$

any help? I tried with telescope but got nothing

Answer (score 3):

**hint**: Expand: $(1+2+\cdots + 2015)^2=(1^2+2^2+\cdots + 2015^2)+2S \to \left(\dfrac{2015(2015+1)}{2}\right)^2 = \dfrac{2015(2015+1)(2\times 2015+1)}{6}+2S \to S = ....$

Comment: Very nice solution. 
$$\frac 12 \left[\left(\sum_{r=1}^{2015}r\right )^2-\sum_{r=1}^{2015}r^2\right]=\frac 12\binom{2016}2^2-\frac 18\binom{4028}3=2.06136\times 10^{12}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$S_N = \sum_{i=1}^N i = \frac{N(N+1)}{2}$$ and note that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{k=i}^{N+1} ik
= \sum_{i=1}^N i (S_{N+1} - S_{i-1})
$$
can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=1}^{2014}((\sum_{i=1}^{2015})n)$ = 4,121,355,747,600

But since you didn't include (1 x 1), subtract that from the number.

4,121,355,747,600 - (1) = **4,121,355,747,599**

---

The logic behind this is simple:

$$(1 \times 2) + ( 1 \times 3) + (1 \times 4) + \cdots + (1 \times 2015) = 1(2 + 3 + 4 +\cdots + 2015) = 1 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{2015}\right)$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2015} = 2,031,120$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\left(1 \times \sum_{i=1}^{2015}\right) + (2 \times \sum_{i=1}^{2015}) + (3 \times \sum_{i=1}^{2015}) + \cdots + (2014 \times \sum_{i=1}^{2015}) = \sum_{n=1}^{2014}((\sum_{n=1}^{2015})n)$$

$$= \sum_{n=1}^{2014}(2,031,120)n$$

$$= 4,121,355,747,600$$

Comment: I think your solution is wrong